# How to round a number to its lowest value using int() in python

Tags: python, rounding, truncate

What I want is:

```
if 1700 / 1000 = 1.7 = int(1) # I want this to be True
   lst.append("T")
```

My original code was:

```
if 1700 / 1000 == int(1) # This is False and I want it to be True
   lst.append("T")
```

The if statement is False because the answer is 1.7 and not 1. I would like this to be True. So I want the 1.7 to round down to 1 using int so that the if statement will be True.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Some documentation that will help: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions . Note that "division" has three flavors. You are looking for the last (which does a floordiv).

Answer (score 5):

`//` always provide `integer` value. If you want to get always `integer` then use it otherwise follow `int(a/b)`

```
if 1700 // 1000 == int(1):  # I want this to be True
    lst.append("T")
```

Comment: This works because / does a floating point division and // does an integer division.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to put the int on the other side:

```py
if int(1700 / 1000) == 1
   lst.append("T")
```

i.e. round the 1700/1000 to an integer before comparing it,
or use `//`, which is integer division and discards the fraction part:

```py
if 1700 // 1000 == 1
   lst.append("T")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either use the `//` operator (integer division) or use the `floor` function from the `math` module:

```
>>> from math import floor
>>> floor(1.7/1)
1
>>> floor(1.7/1) == int(1)
True
>>> 1.7 // 1
1.0
>>> 1.7 // 1 == 1
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
if int(1700/1000) == 1 # I want this to be True
   lst.append("T")
```

int(1700/1000) will convert the 1.7 into 1 by ignoring the decimal portion of the number

Answer (score 1):

Everything brilliant is simple

```
if int(1700 / 1000) == int(1): 
   lst.append("T")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the floor and ceil functions. The floor function rounds to the last number, whereas ceil to the next. In your case, you need to do it like this:

```
import math

if math.floor(1700 / 1000) == int(1):
   print("TRUE")
else:
    print("FALSE")
```

[image: using floor in python]

Answer (score 0):

You could round up or down in Python by 'floor' and 'ceil' methods in the 'math' library.

```
from math import floor, ceil
print (floor(1.7), ' , ', ceil(1.7))
```

The result will be

```
1 , 2
```

This will work in either Python 2.x or Python 3.x